# How can I implement the SearchBar method to search keywords for more than one element from the Class in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, searchbar

Here I have the SearchBar method, which, at the moment, searching keywords from my TITLE element of the Post Class. But I want to search by TITLE and LOCATION, which is the second element in my Post Class. How to add the LOCATION element from my Post class to the searchBar method?

```
private void searchBarmainPage_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {    
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
        {
            var keyword = e.NewTextValue; 
            conn.CreateTable<PostClass>();
            var posts = conn.Table<PostClass>().ToList();
                if(keyword.Length >= 1)
                {
                var results = posts.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()));
                listViewMainPage.ItemsSource = results;
                 listViewMainPage.IsVisible = true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                listViewMainPage.IsVisible = false;
                }
            }

        } catch (NullReferenceException r)
        {
        }catch (Exception m)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `||` operator to check if the keyword is contained inside the Title or inside the Location.

If you want the keyword to be in both places at the same type, you should use `&&`

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
        {
            var keyword = e.NewTextValue; 
            conn.CreateTable<PostClass>();
            var posts = conn.Table<PostClass>().ToList();
                if(keyword.Length >= 1)
                {
                var results = posts.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()) || x.Location.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower())  );
                listViewMainPage.ItemsSource = results;
                 listViewMainPage.IsVisible = true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                listViewMainPage.IsVisible = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for answering. However, by implementing `var results = posts.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()) || x.Location.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()) );` the function is not working any more. There is no error. However, when typing keywords nothing is happening. Any ides why?

Comment: Can you debug and check if the `results` variable has any value inside?

Comment: Yes, It does have value inside 'Appname.Model.PostClass'

Comment: adding an extra pair of () did not work unfortunately

Comment: I meant to check if the `posts.Where()` method returns a empty List

Comment: posts.where() is returning the count of posts. It is not empty

Comment: try adding `ToList()` to the end of the query